# WPF Clipping with a shape

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a 3..2..1 countdown in the form of a user control. Something like [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-4he5VBGRjHM/Tgc5YhrgUTI/AAAAAAAAAR4/tzPbabYtmf0/s1600/83countdown.jpg). My Idea was to create two rectangles on top of each other, one light and one dark and have a radial circle as the clipper for the dark rectangle. The radial circle would have Angle property animated so it would turn around.

I found an implementation of the radial circle and bound the Clip property of the rectangle on the RenderedGeometry property of my circle. Here is the result :

[image: Problem Screenshot]

The red stroke is the shape of my clipper. This seems to be an odd behavior of the clipping but I sort of understand it but I would like to know if there was a way of going around the 
fact that my clipped object seems to use the RenderedGeometry in a weird way.

**Edit 1** : The effect I am looking for http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FPHTo5V2BQ

Comment: This seems a bit overcomplicated, what's the effect you're after exactly?

Comment: Something like this : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FPHTo5V2BQ . And yes I sometimes do over complicate things but it's part of my research process. I have not yet found a simple way of doing it.

Comment: I'll have to check it out later, unfortunately they restrict youtube at the office for us :(

Comment: Could you post the XAML code and any relevant code-behind (and not just a screenshot)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple derived Shape control shown below draws the countdown rectangle. You have to set its `Fill` (and perhaps `Stroke`), `Width`, `Height` and `Angle` properties, and you can animate `Angle` from 0 to 360.

```
public class CountdownRect : Shape
{
    static CountdownRect()
    {
        WidthProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CountdownRect),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((CountdownRect)o).UpdateGeometry()));

        HeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CountdownRect),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((CountdownRect)o).UpdateGeometry()));

        StrokeLineJoinProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CountdownRect),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PenLineJoin.Round));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(CountdownRect),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((o, e) => ((CountdownRect)o).UpdateGeometry()));

    public double Angle
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AngleProperty, value); }
    }

    private readonly StreamGeometry geometry = new StreamGeometry();

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get { return geometry; }
    }

    private void UpdateGeometry()
    {
        if (!double.IsNaN(Width) && !double.IsNaN(Height))
        {
            var angle = ((Angle % 360d) + 360d) % 360d;
            var margin = StrokeThickness / 2d;
            var p0 = new Point(margin, margin);
            var p1 = new Point(Width - margin, margin);
            var p2 = new Point(Width - margin, Height - margin);
            var p3 = new Point(margin, Height - margin);

            using (var context = geometry.Open())
            {
                if (angle == 0d)
                {
                    context.BeginFigure(p0, true, true);
                    context.LineTo(p1, true, false);
                    context.LineTo(p2, true, false);
                    context.LineTo(p3, true, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    var x = p2.X / 2d;
                    var y = p2.Y / 2d;
                    var a = Math.Atan2(x, y) / Math.PI * 180d;
                    var t = Math.Tan(angle * Math.PI / 180d);

                    context.BeginFigure(new Point(x, y), true, true);

                    if (angle < a)
                    {
                        context.LineTo(new Point(x + y * t, p0.Y), true, false);
                        context.LineTo(p1, true, false);
                        context.LineTo(p2, true, false);
                        context.LineTo(p3, true, false);
                        context.LineTo(p0, true, false);
                    }
                    else if (angle < 180d - a)
                    {
                        context.LineTo(new Point(p2.X, y - x / t), true, false);
                        context.LineTo(p2, true, false);
                        context.LineTo(p3, true, false);
                        context.LineTo(p0, true, false);
                    }
                    else if (angle < 180d + a)
                    {
                        context.LineTo(new Point(x - y * t, p2.Y), true, false);
                        context.LineTo(p3, true, false);
                        context.LineTo(p0, true, false);
                    }
                    else if (angle < 360d - a)
                    {
                        context.LineTo(new Point(p0.X, y + x / t), true, false);
                        context.LineTo(p0, true, false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.LineTo(new Point(x + y * t, p0.Y), true, false);
                    }

                    context.LineTo(new Point(x, p0.Y), true, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can clip your rectangle by using an `ArcSegment` in the clipping `PathGeometry`, and animate that `ArcSegment`'s endpoint (`Point`).

The endpoint can be animated with a `PointAnimationUsingPath` animation, using an identical `ArcSegment` as its path. Below is a suggestion based on Charlez Petzold's excellent answer here: [Drawing pie slices](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/81a0a141-d02f-4713-93fc-9f2547597c7f#da644ea6-aa29-41a7-b824-16e5449d0f16)

```
<UserControl ... >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Point x:Key="SweepCenter" X="100" Y="100" />
        <Size x:Key="SweepRadius" Width="130" Height="130" />

        <!-- Start sweeping at twelve o'clock.. -->
        <Point x:Key="SweepStart" X="100" Y="-30" />
        <!-- ..and keep sweeping clockwise until we're (almost) back at the start point: -->
        <Point x:Key="SweepEnd" X="99.99" Y="-30" />

        <Storyboard x:Key="Sweeper" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="False" >

            <PointAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="arc"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point"
                                     Duration="0:0:5">
                <PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="{StaticResource SweepStart}">
                            <ArcSegment Size="{StaticResource SweepRadius}" 
                                        Point="{StaticResource SweepEnd}"
                                        SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                                        IsLargeArc="True" />
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            </PointAnimationUsingPath>

            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="arc"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsLargeArc" >
                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.5" Value="True" />
                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="False" />
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid Width="200" Height="200" >
        <Rectangle Fill="Black" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Gray" >
            <Rectangle.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Sweeper}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </Rectangle.Triggers>
            <Rectangle.Clip>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="{StaticResource SweepCenter}" 
                                IsClosed="True" >
                        <LineSegment Point="{StaticResource SweepStart}" />
                        <ArcSegment x:Name="arc"
                                    Size="{StaticResource SweepRadius}"
                                    Point="{StaticResource SweepStart}"
                                    SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Rectangle.Clip>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```